# Passing in variable values when calling `sass` from command line

Tags: sass

This question was asked a few months ago but ended not having an answer so I'm wondering if in that time one has come up.

I want to use mixins to turn my relative url's into absolute ones without hard-coding the host in the file.  I'm not using rails or ruby ... rendering it standalone, called by a web server written in a different language.  it'd be nice to be able to specify the base/host during the command line call -- with the server supplying the proper protocol, host, port, etc. for sass to just tack on relative url's at the end of.

The 'solution' that the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153613/provide-sass-variables-definitions-on-command-line) had was that the asker didn't really need this functionality.  Maybe I can do this another way?

(I'd also rather not interpolate the entire sass file with a pre-processing script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you seek is already part of Compass.  Use the [URL helper functions](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url) for your assets (images, stylesheets, fonts)

```
.foo {
    background-image: image_url('my-image.png');
}
```

The config.rb options relevant to your question are:

- http_path
- images_dir
- relative_assets

([see all configuration variables](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/))

If you want to have settings that are different for development vs production mode, you can do this:

```
if environment == :production
    relative_assets = true
elsif environment == :development
    relative_assets = false
end
```

To change modes, your command requires the addition of the environment flag:

```
compass compile -e production
```

Comment: how would i then render the css?  Do i just replace all calls of `sass my_file.scss` with `compass my_file.scss`?  I can use compass as a standalone sass renderer?

Comment: `compass` is intended to replace `sass` as your command line tool.  `compass watch` or `compass compile` would be how you would run it, instead of specifying files or directories.

Comment: and this can all work without using ruby as your actual server?

Comment: I only have Ruby for the purpose of running Sass/Compass, so yes.