# How to check console option inside sass file

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am trying to do :

```
@if (debug)
  .crazyClass {}
```

And I would like the debug variable to come from the console when I compile my sass, is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506578/use-variable-defined-in-config-rb-in-scss-files or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157315/passing-in-variable-values-when-calling-sass-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject variables into SASS or set variables via the command line. I really wish we could because it would simplify issues like this.

I know of only two ways of doing conditional compiles.

### Use Different Entry Points

Use different SASS files as the entry points for compile. Your project might look something like this.

```
/www
   /css
      _styles.scss
      dev.scss
      prod.scss
```

The `dev.scss` file would set `debug` to true, and import `_style.scss`, but the `prod.scss` would set `debug` to false, and import `_style.scss`. Both produce the output CSS file but for different environments.

### Use Different Import Paths

You can configure SASS to use different import paths and setup your project files like this.

```
/www
   /css
      /dev
         _config.scss
      /prod
         _config.scss
      styles.scss
```

The `styles.scss` would just do a `@import "config"` at the top, and depending on which path is set the corresponding `_config.scss` file would be imported.