# Pass parameters to scss

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, sass

My website is multi-language and in some languages direction of all elements are `ltr` and in the other ones they are `rtl`. there is exactly similar situation for `text-align`

I'm using scss (for the first time) I wonder whether I should create styles.rtl.scss and styles.ltr.scss files separately or I can pass parameter to the scss file and use it with a mixin like:

```
@mixin dir($dir){
direction: $dir
}
```

Comment: Your first option is many times simpiler then your second option.

Comment: Is there a technical problem here, or are you just asking for opinions?

Comment: well actually as I said i'm using scss for the first time. and I don't know much what I'm doing. the problem of the first options is that I should create separate files for rtl and ltr styles and update them both everytime. but what I really want to know is that is the second options possible?

Comment: @cimmanon I'm not asking for opinion, I want to know is it possible to pass parameter to scss. page defines a variable like `$dir : ltr;` and pass it to scss file so that both style.rtl.css and style.ltr.css files are created programatically?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153613/provide-sass-variables-definitions-on-command-line