# How can I set a sass variable using an environment variable?

Tags: sass, build-process, development-environment

I'm using Gulp as my build system.

I need to identify links pointing to external websites with the scss following rule:

```
// Links to external websites
a[href*='//']:not([href*='example.com']) {
    &::after {
        content: ' \e895';
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
    }
}
```

OR

```
$baseURL: 'localhost:3000'; // Set this variable based on environment
a[href*='//']:not([href*='#{$baseurl}']) {
    ...
}
```

When I'm running a development server the address I'm serving files from is `localhost:3000`, not `example.com`.  The result is that every single link on the website (on the dev server) has a small icon indicating the link goes to an external website, which is really distracting.

What's the best way to set a scss variable based on an environment setting?

---

**Edit:**
This solution works, but it introduces a temporary file, which I'm not wild about.  I moved my `_variables.scss` into the scss root, I process this file and output it into the `base` subdirectory where it is used to compile the scss.  I would then add `scss/base/_variables.scss` to my `.gitignore` to avoid committing to version control.

**_variables.scss**

```
$baseURL: '/* @echo PATH */';
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
// Set baseurl as Sass variable -- used to identify external links
gulp.task('sass-vars', function () {
  var baseURL = (config.production) ? 'example.com' : 'localhost:3000';
  return gulp.src('./scss/_variables.scss')
    .pipe($.preprocess({context: {PATH: baseURL}}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./scss/base'));
});
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/280

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153613/provide-sass-variables-definitions-on-command-line, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506578/use-variable-defined-in-config-rb-in-scss-files

Comment: Both of those solutions use ruby/compass which includes a config file that allows you to set sass environment variables.

Comment: @Roy I did the same thing although I separated it out into a file called `_environment.scss` and then imported that into my `_variables.scss` and then simply add it to my build step. Not sure if there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

To get environment variables there's a package: [gulp-env](https://github.com/crystalschang/gulp-env)

To remove these links from static files: [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess)

But it's also important to check these changed files, not to commit them as a development version. Hooks to your VCS is an option.