# Can Angular CLI pass environment-specific settings to Sass variables?

Tags: angular, sass, webpack, angular-cli

When building an Angular 2 app using Angular CLI/webpack, I'd like to specify values for a few Sass variables. Like make some `url(#{$my-base-path}/...)` or `$fa-font-path` point to a CDN in production, or simply set different background colors for acceptance and production builds.

I like how Angular CLI picks a config from, e.g., `environments/environment.prod.ts`. But I'd also happily use additional command line parameters for `ng build`, but no luck so far:

- Without Angular CLI, I guess I could [use Sass custom functions on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153613/provide-sass-variables-definitions-on-command-line), but I don't know how I could use that approach along with Angular CLI.
- Maybe I can specify the path to some specific `my-variables.sccs` to use for all Sass compilations?
- Webpack's sass-loader [states the following](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#environment-variables), but I've no clue if I can use that with Angular CLI:

  > Environment variables
  >
  > If you want to prepend Sass code before the actual entry file, you can
  >   simply set the `data` option. In this case, the sass-loader will not
  >   override the `data` option but just append the entry's content. This is
  >   especially useful when some of your Sass variables depend on the
  >   environment:
  >
  > ```
  > {
  >     loader: "sass-loader",
  >     options: {
  >         data: "$env: " + process.env.NODE_ENV + ";"
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to the comment by Arjan I solved the problem by creating multiple apps with different `.scss` file in `.angular-cli.json`

**Step 1:**
Create several folders with `.scss` file for each environment, all the `.scss` files has the same filename

```
|- src
  ...
  |- environments
    |- environment-scss
      |- globalVars.scss
    |- environment-prod-scss
      |- globalVars.scss
  ...
```

in src/environment-scss/globalVars.scss:

```
  $my-base-path: 'YOUR/DEV/PATH'
```

in src/environment-prod-scss/globalVars.scss:

```
  $my-base-path: 'YOUR/PROD/PATH'
```

**Step 2:**
Add multiple apps in  `.angular-cli.json` [( Angular-cli Wiki Here )](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps), and add `stylePreprocessorOptions` entry in each app object for each environment [( Angular-cli Wiki Here )](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles).

```
"apps": [
  {
    "root": "src",
    ...
    "name": "dev",
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
        "environments/environment-scss"
      ]
    }
    ...
  },
  {
    "root": "src",
    ...
    "name": "prod",
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
        "environments/environment-prod-scss"
      ]
    }
    ...
  }  
],
```

**Step 3:**
Import the `globalVars.scss` where the env-specific variables needed. **Do not use the relative path**

```
@import "globalVars";
```

When using `ng build --app=dev`, the `$my-base-path` will be `'YOUR/DEV/PATH'`, when using `ng build --app=prod`, the `$my-base-path` will be `'YOUR/PROD/PATH'`

Comment: Nice, we tested and this works great, and allowed us to remove the dummy components introduced by the earlier answer.

Comment: If you dont have `"root": "src"`, the paths have to start from `src` as in `src/environments/environment-scss` and `src/environments/environment-prod-scss`

Answer (score 8):

As of Angular CLI 6, `environment.ts` is no longer automatically replaced by `environment.prod.ts` for production builds. Instead, it [uses a new option `fileReplacements` in `angular.json`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/application-environments.md).

For **the future** CLI 6.1, this can nicely be extended to use the very same mechanism for Sass files. Just create some `environment.scss` and `environment.prod.scss`, reference the first in some `@import "../../environments/environment"` in your Sass file, and adjust your `angular.json` file:

```json
"defaultProject": "ponyracer",
...
"projects": {
  "ponyracer": {
    ...,
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        ...,
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              },
              {
                // BEWARE: this needs Angular CLI 6.1; see below
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.scss",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.scss"
              }
            ],
            ...
```

Finally, build using `build --prod`, `ng build --configuration=production` or `build ponyracer --configuration=production`.

Easy and consistent.

But **BEWARE**, until Angular CLI 6.1 is released, the above [won't work](https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/885):

> Currently, the file replacement functionality works only for TS files. More specifically - it works only for files that are part of the webpack compiler host.

Apparently, the bug fix [will be included in CLI 6.1](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10881#issuecomment-389644466).

Comment: This does not work for me as of 6.2.2 and I'm reading others as late as 7.3 where this still does not work.

Comment: This is a great workaround: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11451#issuecomment-424715627

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.

Only the environment .ts files. No SASS.

Here's something else you can do:

- Use TS environment files to get some config value (save to global variable or something in `main.ts` - I think there used to be issues loading it in other files)
- Have two empty components with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, so that their SASS files are global
- `*ngIf` each of the 2 components based on the value you stored from environment file

One other way is to call `ng eject` to get the CLI to convert the project into a normal webpack project that you can modify its config (RC0 and above).

Comment: ...however: so this would mean that the empty components would need to include all Sass sources (or at least all sources that use the variables), which might be cumbersome if many real components have their own Sass files that use the variables.

Comment: Just for future reference: I created 3 dummy components with `styleUrls` pointing to, e.g, `environment.prod.scss`. These set some Sass variables and then `@import` the Sass that my real component used to list in its `styleUrls` (which is now empty). As those real components use `:host deep` and scoped CSS, I could not make the styles global. Instead, I nested repeatedly: `<env-dev *ngIf=...><my-component></my-component></env-dev> <env-acc *ngIf=...><my-component></my-component></env-acc> <env-prod *ngIf=...><my-component></my-component></env-prod>`  Plain ugly, but workable for now.