# It's possible to insert angular environment variable into scss?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I'm trying to find a way to change how my `scss` is compiled based on a "profile" variable environment. 
My app will be installed on different locations, witch with different theme, but all the `css` is the same. I just need to change what `color palette` will be used, during compilation.
My app already have on the `environments.ts` a `profile` variable, that will be used for `brand image`.

I was thinking in something like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  profile: 'appX'
  apiUrl: 'http://mydoainX.com/api/',
};
```

and, on the `scss`:

```
$profile: environment.profile;
```

It's possible to do something like this?

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about overwriting that css value with locally stored copy in each environment from another css file: import url("department_store.css"); Not sure about sass but I think they use include for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually a found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515893/can-angular-cli-pass-environment-specific-settings-to-sass-variables/46486499#46486499), witch lead me to the solution.

It says to create multiple apps with different `.scss` file in `.angular-cli.json`.

**Step 1:**
Create several folders with `.scss` file for each environment, all the `.scss` files has the same filename:

```
|- src
  ...
  |- environments
    |- app1
      |- scss
        |- globalVars.scss
      |- environment.dev.ts
      |- environment.prod.ts
    |- app2
      |- scss
        |- globalVars.scss
      |- environment.dev.ts
      |- environment.prod.ts
  ...
```

in src/environments/app1/scss/globalVars.scss:
      $profile: 'app1'.

in src/environments/app2/scss/globalVars.scss:
      $profile: 'app2'.

**Step 2:**

> Add multiple apps in `.angular-cli.json` [( Angular-cli Wiki Here
>   )](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps), and add `stylePreprocessorOptions` entry in each app object for
>   each environment [( Angular-cli Wiki Here )](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles).

```
"apps": [
  {
    ...
    "name": "app1",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/app1/environment.dev.ts",
      "prod": "environments/app1/environment.prod.ts"
    },
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
        "environments/app1/scss"
      ]
    }
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    "name": "app2",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/app2/environment.dev.ts",
      "prod": "environments/app2/environment.prod.ts"
    },
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
        "environments/app2/scss"
      ]
    }
    ...
  },
  ...
],
```

**Step 3:**

> Import the `globalVars.scss` where the env-specific variables needed.
>   **Do not use the relative path!**
>
> ```
> @import "globalVars";
> ```

When using `ng build --app=app1`, the `$profile` will be `'app1'`and so on.

**Step 4:**
On my `theme.scss` i used the variable like this:

```
.my-style {
  @if $profile == 'app1' {@include angular-material-theme($theme-app1);}
  @if $profile == 'app2' {@include angular-material-theme($theme-app2);}

  &.contrast {
    @include angular-material-theme($theme-contrast);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't and won't get the environment variable saved in `environment.prod.ts`, and also not the right answer to the question.