# Change Angular Material theme variable on build

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular6, angular-material-6

I need to customize my angular 6 application to change a primary color depending on build (I have to change primary color to another one on dev and production). Is there any straightforward solution to change the color on build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [css custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to change a css value dynamically.

Setup e. g. in `AppModule`'s constructor:

```
let primaryColor: string;
if (environment.production) {
  primaryColor = 'green';
} else {
  primaryColor = 'red';
}
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', primaryColor);
```

And then use the value in your css with:

```
color: var(--primary-color)
```

For a SASS solution, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47201229/4694994).

Comment: Great! The SASS solution is what I was looking for! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [reported issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10881), it seems that version 6.1 will support file replacements other than just typescript files.

If yes, you should be able to replace your `my-own-theme.scss` depending on configuration profile. (defined inside angular.json)