# How to force CSS urls to respect webpack's publicPath setting?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, css-loader

my angular app ends up being deployed to web server with different virtual paths such as:

```
http://website.com/app1/
http://website.com/app2/
```

To get them both work properly, at the build stage I change angular's `<base href=>` and webpack's `publicUrl` options to match specific virtual path `app1` or `app2`.

The urls in my `index.html` are properly changed from 
`<img src='hello.png'/>` to `<img src='app1/hello.png'/>` but the urls inside the css and sass are not changed at all.

I use `style-loader`, `css-loader` and `sass-loader` plugins like that:

```
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')],
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        }
```

And lets say my css is:

```
body {
  background-image: url(bg.png);
}
```

Can I force webpack to add `publicUrl` to `bg.png` and load it from `url(app1/bg.png)`?

UPD:
There is no way to use Angular CLI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Angular CLI pass environment-specific settings to Sass variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515893/can-angular-cli-pass-environment-specific-settings-to-sass-variables)

Comment: @jcal not really, I can't use angular CLI at all. I've updated the question

Comment: take a look at [https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#environment-variables](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#environment-variables)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could work (not tested):

**webpack.config.js**

```
...

{
  loader: "sass-loader",
  options: {
    data: "$baseUrl: " + process.env.baseUrl + ";"
  }
}

...
```

**scss:**

```
body {
  background-image: url($baseUrl + 'bg.png');
}
```

this way you could also change `process.env.baseUrl` in the build stage

Comment: this is doable but won't help with *.css

Comment: whats holding you back from changing it to scss?

Comment: @d.dizhevsky [https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env)