# define a global sass variable with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-hybrid

In my project, I need to inject a global variable to be used across the app, from an environment file, into SCSS files.

Following an advice such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515893/can-angular-cli-pass-environment-specific-settings-to-sass-variables), isn't possible for me since the app contains ~50 different possible configs, so maintaining so many projects in `angular.json` is just not feasible.

In our current setup, using webpack, we used the `data` option for `sass-loader` to inject what ever variable imported from the environment file. 
This is currently impossible with angular-cli - making the migration impossible.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: environment files are interpreted at run time, while SCSS variables are resolved at compile time. You're thinking the wrong way.

Comment: environment files are often read during webpack at build time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up succesfuly using [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus), followed [this](https://medium.jonasbandi.net/angular-cli-and-moment-js-a-recipe-for-disaster-and-how-to-fix-it-163a79180173) article, and used this `webpack.extra.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const configs = require('./src/configs');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)],
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              includePaths: ["src/ng1/assets/sass"],
              data: `
                    $templateTheme: ${configs.templateTheme};
                  `,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```